# Is handoff / continuity (iOS 8+) supported in iTunes to seamlessly switch playback between Mac and iOS?

Tags: itunes, continuity, ios

I'd love to be able to control my currently playing iPhone song from my Mac. Does anyone know if handoff / continuity is supported in iOS 8 or 9 Music.app?

Comment: I would actually love that in a different way... To be able to take where I currently am on an album or playlist in iTunes, handoff to my iPhone halfway through a track, and continue listening on my way home... That would be nice!

Comment: @Jowie I think perhaps this question should get a new title, as that’s what I imagined it would be. (On [several](http://www.loopinsight.com/2014/11/21/wish-list-handoff-for-itunes-and-music/) [people’s](https://sixcolors.com/post/2014/11/wish-list-handoff-for-itunes-and-music/) [wishlists](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/39tv1j/i_hope_with_apple_music_we_get_the_ability_to/).) BTW, for remote control, also check out [Airfoil](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handoff is not supported in Music.app, however your use case (control media playback on your iPhone from a Mac) would be more along the lines of what the Apple Remote app does, just in reverse.

[Tunes Remote](http://tunesremote.com/) allows you to control one device from another device or a Mac. I have not used the software, so YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

As several other people have already answered, no, at this time iTunes and Music do not support Handoff.

However, there used to be a piece of software that did just this, called [Seamless](http://fivedetails.com/seamless/). It was removed from the App Stores, though, after “Apple breakingly removed a component from iOS that Seamless used to allow for iPhone<->Mac communication.” The [developers say](http://fivedetails.com/seamless/support/) they “can work around it, but it'll take some time.” Maybe it will come back at some point, in which case it could be a good workaround.

Comment: Rereading, that's not quite what you asked about, but I expect it still might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Handoff/Continutity is not supported in Music.app 
Maybe [Tunes Remote](http://tunesremote.com) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

it appears not. I've always thought being able to continue playing a playlist or album on another device is well over due. I'd use it much more that safari or mail as that was kind of available anyway with the iCloud tab in safari or the drafts folder in mail.